# How to fix 'admob dependency' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dependencies, admob

I was using ad_mob dependency:0.5.2 for my app to run and it worked well but when I tried building apk through flutter build apk --release it shown me error-

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources'.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output: C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:208: error: resource android:attr/fontVaria
tionSettings not found.
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:209: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found
.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Azhan Khan.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\776897f19ca1f56b9e14581d21b8d456\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
--manifest
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\aapt_friendly_merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\aapt\AndroidManifes
t.xml
-o
C:\Users\AZHANK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\aapt-8063817246819914891-out
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color_common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color_common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal
_background.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_googleg_disabled_color_18.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_googleg_standard_color_18.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_notification_bg_low_normal.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_notification_bg_normal.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4_notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png.flat

-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xxhdpi-v4_common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal
_background.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xxhdpi-v4_common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_norma
l_background.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xxhdpi-v4_common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal
_background.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xxhdpi-v4_common_google_signin_btn_text_light_norma
l_background.9.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xxhdpi-v4_googleg_disabled_color_18.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable-xxhdpi-v4_googleg_standard_color_18.png.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml.flat

-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml.fla
t
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml.flat

-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml.flat

-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml.fla
t
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml.flat

-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_notification_bg.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_notification_bg_low.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_notification_icon_background.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\drawable_notification_tile_bg.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout-v16_notification_template_custom_big.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout-v21_notification_action.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout-v21_notification_action_tombstone.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout-v21_notification_template_custom_big.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout-v21_notification_template_icon_group.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_browser_actions_context_menu_page.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_browser_actions_context_menu_row.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_action.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_action_tombstone.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_media_action.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_media_cancel_action.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_big_media.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_big_media_custom.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_big_media_narrow_custom.xml.fla
t
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_icon_group.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_lines_media.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_media.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_media_custom.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_part_chronometer.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\layout_notification_template_part_time.xml.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-af_values-af.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-am_values-am.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ar_values-ar.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-as_values-as.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-az_values-az.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-b+sr+Latn_values-b+sr+Latn.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-be_values-be.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-bg_values-bg.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-bn_values-bn.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-bs_values-bs.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ca_values-ca.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-cs_values-cs.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-da_values-da.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-de_values-de.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-el_values-el.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-en-rAU_values-en-rAU.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-en-rCA_values-en-rCA.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-en-rGB_values-en-rGB.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-en-rIN_values-en-rIN.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-en-rXC_values-en-rXC.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-es-rUS_values-es-rUS.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-es_values-es.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-et_values-et.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-eu_values-eu.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-fa_values-fa.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-fi_values-fi.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-fr-rCA_values-fr-rCA.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-fr_values-fr.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-gl_values-gl.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-gu_values-gu.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-hi_values-hi.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-hr_values-hr.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-hu_values-hu.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-hy_values-hy.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-in_values-in.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-is_values-is.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-it_values-it.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-iw_values-iw.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ja_values-ja.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ka_values-ka.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-kk_values-kk.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-km_values-km.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-kn_values-kn.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ko_values-ko.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ky_values-ky.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-lo_values-lo.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-lt_values-lt.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-lv_values-lv.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-mk_values-mk.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ml_values-ml.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-mn_values-mn.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-mr_values-mr.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ms_values-ms.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-my_values-my.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-nb_values-nb.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ne_values-ne.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-nl_values-nl.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-or_values-or.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-pa_values-pa.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-pl_values-pl.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-pt-rBR_values-pt-rBR.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-pt-rPT_values-pt-rPT.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-pt_values-pt.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ro_values-ro.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ru_values-ru.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-si_values-si.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-sk_values-sk.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-sl_values-sl.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-sq_values-sq.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-sr_values-sr.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-sv_values-sv.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-sw_values-sw.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ta_values-ta.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-te_values-te.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-th_values-th.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-tl_values-tl.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-tr_values-tr.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-uk_values-uk.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-ur_values-ur.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-uz_values-uz.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-v16_values-v16.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-v21_values-v21.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-v24_values-v24.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-vi_values-vi.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-zh-rCN_values-zh-rCN.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-zh-rHK_values-zh-rHK.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-zh-rTW_values-zh-rTW.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values-zu_values-zu.arsc.flat
-R
C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\compiled\release\values_values.arsc.flat
--auto-add-overlay
--non-final-ids
-0
apk
--no-version-vectors
Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done 46.7s

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
```

But when I changed the dependency version to 0.8.0+4 the flutter build apk --release command works and I get the apk but it crashes on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update `firebase_admob` to version `0.9.0` and change following files:

1. Android - https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#androidmanifest-changes

Put following into `AndroidManifest.xml` file just below `<application>` tag:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
```

Replace `[ADMOB_APP_ID]` with app (not the unit) identifier from AdMob dashboard.

2. iOS - https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#infoplist-changes

Put following into `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>[ADMOB_APP_ID]</string>
```

Replace `[ADMOB_APP_ID]` with app (not the unit) identifier from AdMob dashboard.

Additionally if your app crashes for some reason, you can always run `adb logcat` to see the full logs on what happened.

Comment: You do not change the `com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID` -> it should stay as string. The only thing to change is the `[ADMOB_APP_ID]` which should be the identifier of your app within AdMob. It looks like this: `ca-app-pub-################~##########`

Comment: Where should I add this-FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);

Comment: Anywhere you wish basically. I'm doing it in the `main.dart` just before `runApp` call.